# Tuple index out of range in Python

Tags: python, indexing, tuples

```
def max_logged_in(interval_lst,T):
    startArr, endArr = zip(*interval_lst)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    maxOverlap = 0
    currentOverlap = 0
    while (i<T and j<T):
        if (startArr[i] < endArr[j]):
            currentOverlap = currentOverlap + 1
            maxOverlap = max(maxOverlap, currentOverlap)
            i = i + 1
        else:
            currentOverlap = currentOverlap - 1
            j = j + 1
```

The code is supposed to run through the two arrays and find the max overlap give a list such as `[(5,15), (18,25), (3,12), (4, 11), (1,15), (18,19)]` in the given time (`T`).
Running this code is giving me a tuple index error. I can't seem to figure out why it is giving me an index error.

Comment: If `T` > 5, then your `if` will cause the error you got.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? I'm having trouble understanding why.

Comment: what is the value of `T`?

Comment: It can be any random number. In this case it was 30.

Answer (score 1):

If `T` is greater than the length of `interval_lst`, then `i` and/or `j` can get as high as that length, but there is no element in either `startArr` nor `endArr` at that index (since they are each the same length as `interval_lst`).